# Can I assume the joint density of two normals to be bivariate normal?

Tags: probability

I am looking for the joint distribution of two normal, could I assume it is bivariate?  If no, what should I do?

$X_{1}$~$N(0,1)$
$X_{2}$~$N(1,2)$
cov($X_{1}, X_{2})=1$

How do I find the joint density? And $P(X_{1}<X_{2})?$

Comment: You will need to suppy a joint distribution. You haven't specified the problem enough to single out any single joint denstiy. Why not just assume bivariate normality? It's easy to incorporate the covariance into such a distribution. Then, you can examine its predictions to see if it makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: See the answer from user99680 below. You can derive a joint density from the marginal density without more assumptions, especially since COV$\neq$0, so independence is not even possible.

Comment: I CAN work this as a bivariate?  Looking at the definition of bivariate, I do have the pieces of information $\mu_1, \mu_2, \sigma_1, \sigma_2, cov$

Comment: Sorry meant cant...marginals are not enough but you are correct that you have the ingredients to specify one

Comment: How do I find the joint distribution of correlated normals?  Can I say the joint is bivariate?

Comment: You can... Joint normal has a parameter for correlation

Comment: I am a bit stuck integrating joint density.  Could you tell me how to integrate bivariate with bounds $-\infty<x<y$, $-\infty<y<\infty$

Answer (score 1):

The joint distribution of two normals is not necessarily normal; see, e.g:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Two_normally_distributed_random_variables_need_not_be_jointly_bivariate_normal

And here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33354/when-are-two-normally-distributed-random-variables-jointly-bivariate-normal

for a more full discussion.

For $P(X_1<X_2)$, you can rewrite as $P(X_1-X_2 <0)$. For this, you can find the distribution of $-X_2$ , by composing $X_2$ with a function, and then find the
distribution of $X_1-X_2$ by using the convolution of $X_1$ and $-X_2$.

You can see here:( in the "Functions of Random Variables" section) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variables

How to get the distribution of $-X_2$ from that of $X_2$.

The idea is this: if $g(x)$ is an invertible ( or locally-invertible, but f(x)=-x is globally-invertible) , then we use that:

$P(g(X)\leq y)=P(X \leq g^{-1}(y))$. In our case, $g(x)=-x=g^{-1}(x)$ , so that

$P(-X_2>y)=P(X_2 \leq -y)$

Looking at this geometrically, notice this just changes the region of integration.

EXAMPLE:

Say you're in $\mathbb R $, with a cdf $P_{X_2}$ for $X_2$. Then $P(X_2>x)$ is given by

the integral from $x_2$ to $\infty$ , but $P( -X_2>x)=P(X_2\leq -x)$ is the integral

from $-x$ to -$\infty$ . The regions of integration are complementary, in that their

union is the entire space.

After knowing the distribution of $-X_2$, you can find the distribution of $X_1-X_2$ by doing the convolution of $X_1$ with $-X_2$.

Comment: @user13985:Glad it helped.

Comment: how do I find the $X_2$ function?  And do I use Jacobian transformation for convolution?

Comment: No; the change of variable takes you from $X_2$ to $-X_2$, and then you use the Jacobian of the transformation gives you the distribution of $-X_2$. After having the distribution for $-X_2$ . After that, you do the convolution of $X_1$ and $-X_2$.

Comment: do you mean $Y=X_1-X_2$, $P(Y<0)$, and then use Jacobian?

Comment: Well, the issue is that you know the distribution of $X_1$, of $X_2$, but not the distribution of $-X_2$, nor that of $Y=X_1-X_2$ . You first get the distribution of $-Y_2$, by composition; see, e.g., p.211 here: http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf and , after knowing the distribution of $-X_2$, you do the convolution of $X_1$ with $-X_2$, to get the distribution of $Y=X_1-X_2$, as in Ch.7 of the same link

Comment: @user13985: Please see the edits I just did in the bottom of my post.

Comment: isn't the distribution of $-X_2$ just the negative of $X_2$?  Also, chapter 7 says the function has to be strictly increasing.  Doesn't normal increase then decrease?

Comment: @user13985: I think they're referring to the change-of-variable function. Basically, $P(-X_2>y)=P(X_2\leq -y)$. I did a few other edits; I'm sorry, but I need to go work. I'll come back later.

Comment: @user13985: I did another edit; please look at it. Basically, working with $-X_2$ instead of $X_2$ , just changes the region of integration. See the above comments too.

Comment: I am confused why $g(x)=-x=g^{-1}(x)$.  I don't think I've learned it this way before, just curious.

Comment: Do the composition; $g(g(x))=g(-x)=-(-x)=x=Id(x) $, so  $g$ is its own inverse.

Comment: I am really confused, I thought I can integrate $P(x<y)$ using joint density, and then double integral with $dx dy$.

Comment: Could we go to chat at some later point? This way doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Sure, I am online, please let me know what I should do.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11508/discussion-between-user13985-and-user99680)

Comment: Sure, but I cannot do it right now; sorry. How about tomorrow after 4-or-so?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Are you sure two correlated normal is NOT a bivariate?  http://www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg713/Lectures/Lecture713-11-4.pdf